# Formik with Yup - Throwing an Exception when using test() function

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to write a custom validation in Yup to use in my React Formik forms.  Whenever I try to use this custom validation I get the following error "yupError.inner is undefined".

This seems to happen whenever I use the test() function on a String validation.  I've attached one of the situations where it's causing the error.

In a standalone file...

```
export const validate_birthday = Yup.string().required('We need your birthday to make sure it is you')
    .test({
        name: "DOB", 
        message: "We need a valid birthday to make sure it is you",
        test: value => {
               return moment(value).isMoment() &&
               moment(value).isBefore(moment()) &&
               moment(value).isAfter(moment().subtract(120, 'years'))
             }
        });
```

In the React component...

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
     birthday: validate_birthday
});
```

And the screenshot of the error it keeps throwing...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my test function wasn't covering enough situations and was causing a Javascript error during evaluation.

Once I added all the test cases, this worked properly.

```
if (!value || value === '') {
   return false;
}
if (value.replace(' ', '').length < 10) {
   return false;
}
const m = moment(value, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
return (
     m.isValid() &&
     m.isBefore(moment()) &&
     m.isAfter(moment().subtract(120, 'years'))
);
```